# Titanium Errors when building for android emulator

Tags: android, titanium

I have:

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)

Linux falcon 3.2.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Mar 4 22:48:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Titanium Studio, build: 1.0.9.201202141208
(c) Copyright 2011 by Appcelerator, Inc.  All rights reserved.
Build: jenkins-titanium-rcp-master-138 (origin/master)
Date: 14 February 2012, 12:10:43
```

Latest version of android SDK installed, tools dir added to my path and titanium also configured. Inside titanium i have tried Google API starting from 2.2 and upto 3, same error occurs. I am trying to run sample Hello World app.

```
Logfile initialized
[INFO] logfile = ~/Projects/Titanium/Hello World/build.log
[DEBUG] ~/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/1.8.2/android/builder.py simulator Hello World ~/rootfs/android-sdk-linux ~/Projects/Titanium/Hello World com.me.com.hello.world 5 WVGA854 
[INFO] Building Hello World for Android ... one moment
[INFO] Titanium SDK version: 1.8.2 (02/23/12 17:46 59b3a90)
[DEBUG] Waiting for device to be ready ...
[ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]   File "~/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/1.8.2/android/builder.py", line 2083, in <module>
[ERROR]     s.build_and_run(False, avd_id, debugger_host=debugger_host)
[ERROR]   File "~/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/1.8.2/android/builder.py", line 1727, in build_and_run
[ERROR]     self.wait_for_device('e')
[ERROR]   File "~/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/1.8.2/android/builder.py", line 340, in wait_for_device
[ERROR]     devices = self.sdk.list_devices()
[ERROR]   File "~/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/1.8.2/android/androidsdk.py", line 224, in list_devices
[ERROR]     raise Exception(err)
[ERROR] Exception: ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc/memcpy-preload.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded: ignored.
[ERROR]
```

Contents of /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf

```
# Multiarch support
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

[EDIT]

```
Running android, adb, emulator, etc cause:
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc/memcpy-preload.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded: ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc/memcpy-preload.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded: ignored.
```

on cli.

Any suggestions on what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, it is not able to detect the device(emulator) itself. If you are trying to run on the device, go to the App Explorer click on 'run on device' option. OR, if you are trying on emulator let the app launch the emulator itself for the first time, else checkout whether DDMS has listed your emulator or not. If not, kill adb and try to run. Because, your log says, it is not moving to next step to find the emulator/device properly before actually the app gets launched...

Comment: please check the section under [EDIT] in main post.

Comment: Also, running emulator manually works without issues, but yes, those warnings are there.

Comment: Titanium gives lots of warnings, I think you shouldn't worry about all that. It doesn't even show whether it has stopped running the app or it is still running.

Comment: These are actually "errors". And the app never runs so as much as i would like to put this behind me, i can't.